# Light protection for exported database

Tags: android, database, file

In my application I have implemented the possibility to export the database by copying the database file on the sdcard.
Without encrypting the file or require special keys to read it I just want to make sure that anyone who picks the file up is able to read db structure or data just by opening it in a sqlite file reader.

How can I implement a light and simple protection for my file?

The following is my code for db exporting.

```
public void exportDB() {
    final String destFolder = "/"+Constants.Files.APP_FOLDER+"/"+Constants.Files.BACKUP_FOLDER;
    try {
        File myBackupDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + destFolder);
        if(!myBackupDir.exists() || !myBackupDir.isDirectory()) myBackupDir.mkdirs();
        if(myBackupDir.isDirectory()){
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()) {
                final String  currentDBPath= "//data//" + Constants.Files.PACKAGE_NAME + "//databases//" + Constants.Files.DB_NAME;
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(myBackupDir, Constants.Files.DB_NAME);
                if(currentDB.isFile()){
                    copyFile(new FileInputStream(currentDB), new FileOutputStream(backupDB))
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(mTag, "exportDB", e);
    }
}



public static void copyFile(FileInputStream fromFile, FileOutputStream toFile) throws IOException {
    FileChannel fromChannel = null;
    FileChannel toChannel = null;
    try {
        fromChannel = fromFile.getChannel();
        toChannel = toFile.getChannel();
        fromChannel.transferTo(0, fromChannel.size(), toChannel);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fromChannel != null) {
                fromChannel.close();
            }
        } finally {
            if (toChannel != null) {
                toChannel.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the user's data, not yours. Please allow the user to do what the user wants with the user's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/). It has support for [android](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/). You can export it with your existing code since the DB is already encrypted.